# WCF "value cannot be null" error in event log

Tags: .net, wcf, iis, iis-7

The log in my server is full with this error cause by WCF, I guess. I tried for days to find what's causing it, but no luck.
My WCF services (4.0) are hosted in iis and as far as I know, working well.
Maybe someone knows?

[image]

Comment: Something is *not* working well if you're seeing all those errors.  Try taking a look at your service code and see what is logging to the event viewer using "ECF Provider Fault" as the source.

Comment: I found where it's writing this message to the event log, but I can't upload this change to the production server now. Is there a way to disable System.Diagnostics eventLog writing?

Comment: Without making changes on the production server, no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way to stop writing every bit of information to the event log.
That's what I did: I set TraceLevelSwitch to 1 - errors only.

```html
<system.diagnostics>
   <switches>
      <!-- This switch controls data messages. In order to receive data 
         trace messages, change value="0" to value="1" -->
      <add name="DataMessagesSwitch" value="0" />
      <!-- This switch controls general messages. In order to 
         receive general trace messages change the value to the 
         appropriate level. "1" gives error messages, "2" gives errors 
         and warnings, "3" gives more detailed error information, and 
         "4" gives verbose trace information -->
      <add name="TraceLevelSwitch" value="1" />
   </switches>
</system.diagnostics>
```